# Conversion from 2D to 1D array

Tags: java, arrays, implicit-conversion

So I'm working on converting this logic from a 2D application to function in a 1D array. The thing that is mostly confusing to me is the arrays and how their looping will function. Any input would be appreciated!

```html
LcgRandom rand = new LcgRandom();
  
  int[][] triangle = new int[ROWS][];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++) {
   triangle[i] = new int[i + 1];
   //System.out.println(triangle[i]);
   for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    triangle[i][j] = rand.next();
    //System.out.println(triangle[i]);
  }
  
  //Calculate row sums
  int[][] rowSums = new int[triangle.length][];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < rowSums.length; i++) {
   rowSums[i] = new int[triangle[i].length + 1];
   rowSums[i][0] = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    rowSums[i][j + 1] = rowSums[i][j] + triangle[i][j];
  }
  
  //find the smallest triangle
  long minSum = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < triangle[i].length; j++) {
    
    long curSum = 0;
    for (int k = i; k < triangle.length; k++) {
     curSum += rowSums[k][k - i + 1 + j] - rowSums[k][j];
     if (minSum>curSum)
      minSum=curSum;
     System.out.println(minSum);
    }
   }
  }
  return Long.toString(minSum);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to store your 2D array in row major form i.e. you store all row1 elements first, then row2 elements and so on linearly, then you need to adjust your index calculation.

Assuming your 2D array has R rows and C columns, each row has C elements. Thus your indexes are calculated as :

```
array_1d[j + i*C] == array_2d[i][j] // This is true.
```

Hence your 1D array will have `R * C` elements in it.

Comment: So this is iterating through "triangular" data would that mean that there would be "height"*"height"+1 data entries? Or are you saying that the direct implementation could be changed with the above snippet?

Comment: You can allocate `r*c` elements and iterate with the logic given above (for indexing) and the if you do correctly, it should be identical to the 2D case. If the no of columns are different for each row then, your `C` will change accordingly.